# Find the automorphisms for the Galois Group of the minimial polynomial $x^4+1$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

**Determine the splitting field $L$ for this polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$.**

The splitting field of $x^4+1$ must contain the solutions to $$x^4+1=0,$$ that is, $x^4=-1$. So $x^2=\pm i$, and $x=\pm\sqrt{\pm i}$. So, we have  $$L=\mathbb{Q}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{4}\right), \exp\left(\frac{-\pi i}{4}\right) \right).$$ But $\exp\left(\frac{-\pi i}{4}\right)=\exp\left(\frac{7\pi i}{4}\right)$, and so $$L=\mathbb{Q}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{4}\right)\right),$$ b. Since we found a spltting field $L$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, we can state that the following extension $L:\mathbb{Q}$ is normal, and it has degree $4$

**Determine $\Gamma(L:\mathbb{Q})$.**

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_0)$, where $\zeta_0=\exp\left(\frac{\pi i}{4}\right) \in \mathbb{C}$. Now $\zeta_0^4=1$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_0)$ consists of all elements $$p(x)=c_0+c_1\zeta_0+c_2\zeta_0^2+c_3\zeta_0^3,$$ where $c_i \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ for } i=0, \dots, 3$. So all the automorphisms of the field extension are
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\lambda_1 & : & p(x) & \mapsto & c_0+c_1\zeta_0+c_2\zeta_0^2+c_3\zeta_0^3 \\
\lambda_2 & : & p(x) & \mapsto & c_0+c_2\zeta_0+c_3\zeta_0^2+c_1\zeta_0^3 \\
\lambda_3 & : & p(x) & \mapsto & c_0+c_3\zeta_0+c_1\zeta_0^2+c_2\zeta_0^3 \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

I know I need to four automorphism but I am having trouble determining it.

Comment: An automorphism must take $\zeta_0$ to a conjugate; an automorphism is determined by what it does to $\zeta_0$; for each conjugate $\alpha$ of $\zeta_0$, there is an automorphism that takes $\zeta_0$ to $\alpha$. Try to use these facts to find the four automorphisms.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by conjugate if $\alpha$ of $\zeta_0$

Comment: The conjugates of an algebraic number $\beta$ are the zeros of the irreducible polynomial for $\beta$. In your case, the full set of four zeros of $x^4+1$.

Comment: So there is $\lambda(\alpha)=\alpha$, $\lambda(\alpha)=\beta$, $\lambda(\beta)=\beta$, and $\lambda(\beta)=\beta$?

Comment: Huh? are you using the same symbol $\lambda$ for four different things? are you going to tell me what you mean by the symbols $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: No they are different lambdas. But now I am confused about $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I thought they were conjugates of each other

Comment: They aren't anything, until you say what you mean by them. But I see that Lubin has answered your questions.

Comment: It is mighty difficult for your readers to determine what was in Problem 5 from your Midterm exam :-) Yeah, we can guess and still help, no problem. Just wondering!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re dealing with the four primitive eighth roots of unity. Call any one of them $\zeta$, and let this be fixed. The others now are $\zeta^3$, $\zeta^5$, and $\zeta^7=\zeta^{-1}$. Your four automorphisms are the identity, which takes $\zeta$ to $\zeta$, and the three others, which I suppose you can call $\sigma_3$, $\sigma_5$, and $\sigma_7$, with $\sigma_i$ taking $\zeta$ to $\zeta^i$. You can check, for instance, that $\sigma_3\circ\sigma_5=\sigma_7$ in this way: $$\sigma_3(\sigma_5(\zeta))=\sigma_3(\zeta^5)=[\sigma_3(\zeta)]^5=(\zeta^3)^5=\zeta^{15}=\zeta^7=\sigma_7(\zeta)\,.$$ I leave the rest to you.